Animation of a folding table

I need to design a table that will fold. Here is the code that I managed to get, but it's still not what I need. The picture shows a sample of what I want to get.
Ideally, a list of variables should follow at the beginning of the code - the size of the supports, the size of the take-out corner, the place where the support is attached to the countertop.
Thus, by changing the dimensions, I want to see how the table will fold, and manually select the right size ratio so that the table can fold.
\documentclass[border=5,varwidth,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{cmap} % поиск в PDF
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} % кодировка
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % кодировка исходного текста
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    
    \foreach \angle in {0,5,...,90} {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            
            % Задаем фиксированную длину столешницы и поддержек
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\tableLength}{3} % Длина столешницы
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\supportLength}{1.5}
            
            % Положение конца столешницы
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xend}{\tableLength * cos(\angle)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yend}{-\tableLength * sin(\angle)}
            
            % Положение центра столешницы
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\centerX}{0.5 + (\xend - 0.5) / 2}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\centerY}{\yend / 2}
            
            % Положение точки 2 (так, чтобы длина зелёной линии оставалась фиксированной)
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\greenX}{0}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\greenY}{-3}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\orangeX}{\greenX + \supportLength * (cos(\angle) - 0.5)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\orangeY}{\greenY + \supportLength * (sin(\angle) - 0.5)}
            
            % Корректировка длины зелёной линии
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\greenLength}{sqrt((\greenX - \orangeX)^2 + (\greenY - \orangeY)^2)}
            
            % Корректируем координаты точки 2 для фиксированной длины зелёной линии
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\fixedOrangeX}{\greenX + \supportLength * cos(\angle)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\fixedOrangeY}{\greenY + \supportLength * sin(\angle)}
            
            % Вычисление угла для текста
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\textRotationAngle}{- \angle}
            
            % Серый прямоугольник слева от стены (с размером, равным высоте стены)
            \fill[gray!30] (-0.5, -3.2) rectangle (0, 0.2);
            
            % Стена
            \draw[thick] (0,-3.2) -- (0,0.2);
            
            % Вертикальный текст "Стена"
            \node[rotate=90, font=\tiny] at (-0.6, -1.6) {Стена};
            
            % Шарниры
            \draw[thick] (0.5,0) circle (0.1) node[right, font=\tiny] {\tiny 1}; % Сдвинут на 0.5 см вправо
            \draw[thick] (\fixedOrangeX,\fixedOrangeY) circle (0.1) node[below right, font=\tiny] {\tiny 2};
            \draw[thick] (\centerX,\centerY) circle (0.1) node[below right, font=\tiny] {\tiny 3};
            \draw[thick] (0,-3) circle (0.1) node[left, font=\tiny] {\tiny 4};
            
            % Линия от стены к шарниру 1
            \draw[thick, black] (0,0) -- (0.5,0);
            
            % Позиции стола
            \draw[red, thick] (0.5,0) -- (\xend, \yend) node[midway, above, font=\tiny, rotate=\textRotationAngle] {\tiny Столешница}; % Столешница
            \draw[orange, thick] (\fixedOrangeX,\fixedOrangeY) -- (\centerX, \centerY); % Оранжевая подпорка
            \draw[green, thick] (0,-3) -- (\fixedOrangeX,\fixedOrangeY); % Зелёная подпорка
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    
\end{document}

Added by MS-SPO
Here's a version which removed most cyrillic text as far as nodes are concerned, which may make compiling easier for many people here; problem demonstrated in the screenshots (orange line between 2 and 3):
\documentclass[border=5,varwidth,tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{cmap} % поиск в PDF
%\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} % кодировка
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % кодировка исходного текста
%\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} % локализация и переносы
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    
    \foreach \angle in {0,5,...,90} {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            
            % Задаем фиксированную длину столешницы и поддержек
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\tableLength}{3} % Длина столешницы
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\supportLength}{1.5}
            
            % Положение конца столешницы
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\xend}{\tableLength * cos(\angle)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\yend}{-\tableLength * sin(\angle)}
            
            % Положение центра столешницы
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\centerX}{0.5 + (\xend - 0.5) / 2}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\centerY}{\yend / 2}
            
            % Положение точки 2 (так, чтобы длина зелёной линии оставалась фиксированной)
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\greenX}{0}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\greenY}{-3}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\orangeX}{\greenX + \supportLength * (cos(\angle) - 0.5)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\orangeY}{\greenY + \supportLength * (sin(\angle) - 0.5)}
            
            % Корректировка длины зелёной линии
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\greenLength}{sqrt((\greenX - \orangeX)^2 + (\greenY - \orangeY)^2)}
            
            % Корректируем координаты точки 2 для фиксированной длины зелёной линии
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\fixedOrangeX}{\greenX + \supportLength * cos(\angle)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\fixedOrangeY}{\greenY + \supportLength * sin(\angle)}
            
            % Вычисление угла для текста
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\textRotationAngle}{- \angle}
            
            % Серый прямоугольник слева от стены (с размером, равным высоте стены)
            \fill[gray!30] (-0.5, -3.2) rectangle (0, 0.2);
            
            % Стена
            \draw[thick] (0,-3.2) -- (0,0.2);
            
            % Вертикальный текст "Стена"
            \node[rotate=90, font=\tiny] at (-0.6, -1.6) {Stena};%Стена};
            
            % Шарниры
            \draw[thick] (0.5,0)             circle (0.1) node[right, font=\tiny] {\tiny 1}; % Сдвинут на 0.5 см вправо
            \draw[thick] (\fixedOrangeX,\fixedOrangeY) circle (0.1) node[below right, font=\tiny] {\tiny 2};
            \draw[thick] (\centerX,\centerY) circle (0.1) node[below right, font=\tiny] {\tiny 3};
            \draw[thick] (0,-3)              circle (0.1) node[left, font=\tiny] {\tiny 4};
            
            % Линия от стены к шарниру 1
            \draw[thick, black] (0,0) -- (0.5,0);
            
            % Позиции стола
            \draw[red, thick] (0.5,0) -- (\xend, \yend) node[midway, above, font=\tiny, rotate=\textRotationAngle] {\tiny Stolejniza};%Столешница}; % Столешница
            \draw[orange, thick] (\fixedOrangeX,\fixedOrangeY) -- (\centerX, \centerY); % Оранжевая подпорка
            \draw[green, thick] (0,-3) -- (\fixedOrangeX,\fixedOrangeY); % Зелёная подпорка
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    
\end{document}



currently, I have managed to achieve folding the table in the right direction, but the mistake is that the length of the support rack changes at the same time, which cannot be

Two suggestions: 1) many more people could follow your code, if you'd replace the comments by English text (and the node-texts, too), which also makes many packages unneccessary; 2) If I get it right, angle varies the red line. However, reversing the situation might be easier, i.e. varying the angle of the green line. Which in either case suggests, solving the problem first on paper using vectors (coupled movement), and implementing it after that: several angles can't have a solution. (With vectors, you'll most likely also find an analytical optimum.)

Assumption: If the table is in its upright position. The point 2 lies on the line between 4 and 3, meaning the green support and orange middle part are straight aligned.
The intersections library is used to find the point 2 for all angles except 0°.
I had to change the support length so that the point 2 will not be inside the wall.
Code
\documentclass[border=5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xxcolor}

%%% Input
\newcommand*\tableLength{3}     % red
\newcommand*\tableFixed{1.5}    % point 1
\newcommand*\connection{.7}     % halfway along the table
\newcommand*\supportLength{2.5} % green
\newcommand*\supportDepth{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro\middleLength{
  veclen(\connection*\tableLength+\tableFixed, \supportDepth)-\supportLength}
\pgfmathsetmacro\supportAngle{
  atan2(\supportDepth,\tableFixed+\connection*\tableLength)}

%%% Styles
\tikzset{
  point label/.style={
    node font=\tiny, label position=above, inner sep=+.15em, circle,
    fill=white, fill opacity=.5, text opacity=1},
  point/.style={circle, draw, fill=white, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+2pt},
  table/.style=red,
  fixed/.style={black, thick},
  middle/.style=orange,
  support/.style=green,
  wall/.style=gray,
  pl  3/.style={
    label position=-45-\angle, anchor=north west, rotate=-\angle, yshift=+-.15em},
  pl o3/.style={label position=-45, anchor=north west, yshift=+-.15em},
  pl  4/.style={label position=below right, xshift=+.15em},
  length/.style args={#1:#2}{
    sloped, node font=\tiny, node contents={$\num{#2}$}},
%  debug line/.style={draw, help lines},
}
\sisetup{round-precision=3, round-mode=places, round-pad=false}

%%% Helpers
\newcommand*\DrawTable[3]{%
  \draw[table]   (1) -- node[length= Tbl:\tableLength  , above, pos=.9] {} (#1);
  \draw[support] (4) -- node[length=Sprt:\supportLength, below        ] {} (#2);
  \draw[middle] (#2) -- node[length=Mddl:\middleLength , below        ] {} (#3);}
\newcommand*\DrawPoints[2][]{%
  \foreach \x in {#2}
    \node[point, label={[point label, pl #1\x/.try]\x}] at (#1\x) {};}

\begin{document}
\foreach \angle in {0, .25, .5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, ..., 90}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%% all coordinates (prefix o for angle 0°)
\path (         down:\supportDepth ) coordinate                  (4)
    + (\supportAngle:\supportLength) coordinate                  (o2)
      (        right:\tableFixed   ) coordinate                  (1)
    --                               coordinate[pos=\connection] (o3)
    + (        right:\tableLength  ) coordinate                  (oEoT)
      (1)
    --                               coordinate[pos=\connection] (3)
    + (      -\angle:\tableLength  ) coordinate                  (EoT);

%%% if angle is 0° no need for math
\ifdim\angle pt=0pt
  \coordinate (2) at (o2);
\else
  %%% find intersection between circles around 3 and 4
  \path[name path=middle arc, overlay, debug line/.try]
    ([shift=(up:\middleLength)]3)
    arc[start angle=90, delta angle=180, radius=\middleLength];
  \path[name path=support arc, overlay, debug line/.try]
    ([shift=(right:\supportLength)]4)
    arc[start angle=0, delta angle=180, radius=\supportLength];

  \tikzset{name intersections={
    of=middle arc and support arc, sort by=middle arc, by=2}}

  %%% draw unfolded/original construction
  \begin{colormixin}{25!white}
    \DrawTable{oEoT}{o2}{o3}
    \DrawPoints[o]{2, 3}
  \end{colormixin}
\fi

%%% fixed elements
\fill[wall] (up:.5) coordinate (wt)
                    rectangle (-1,-\supportDepth-.5)
                    coordinate (wb);
\draw[fixed] (wt) -- (wt|-wb);
\draw[fixed] (0,0) -- (1);

%%% folded table
\DrawTable{EoT}{2}{3}
\DrawPoints{1, ..., 4}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}

Output


Super! You have definitely solved the task, but before closing this issue, I want to clarify a few points:

Why, when setting point 3 to a position greater than 0.5 from the center (for example, \create a connection{0.7} % halfway around the table) I get a warning "Table.Tex: error: 76: package error pgf: no form of the name crossroads-1' is known. \end of {tikzpicture}}"



As I understand it, the length of the orange rack is calculated automatically. However, I do not know its received length. For practical use in the manufacture of a table, it is necessary to know all the dimensions. Maybe it would be ideal to put all the dimensions on the drawing in this picture?


@Антон Yeah, some calculation didn't consider \connections properly, I've fixed that now. I've also updated the answer with the values a long the lines and the upright position in faded colors (this also takes care of the bounding box being the same size in all pages).

Perfect!
Do I understand correctly that in order for the table to fold, you selected the length value experimentally? (in fact, this is a graphical method for solving the problem).
Have you used the rules of geometry in determining the length of the support?

And the last question:
Is it possible to make the frame width fixed?
I came across the fact that when the table is small, I get a small PDF frame, when formatting into GIF, the quality is poor.
And for a large table, the program freezes.
I would like to set the actual dimensions in meters: the length of the countertop, for example, 1 meter.
I'm sorry that I didn't formulate this earlier in my question, I just realized it now, and I want everything to work perfectly!

@Антон Is the frame width not fixed now? Otherwise use the max bounding box key as used in the first version of my answer. If you want a unit replace \num{#2} with \qty{#2}{\metra}.
